# Get the data from the database NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to make a real time system where admin can create the message from the admin panel and the client can receive the messages instantly using the nodejs .

I have made this code

```
var express   =    require("express");
var mysql     =    require('mysql');
var app       =    express();

var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit : 100, //important
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : '1234',
database : 'website',
debug    :  false
});

function handle_database(req,res) {

pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
    if (err) {
      connection.release();
      res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
      return;
    }

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

    connection.query("select * from messages",function(err,rows){
        connection.release();
        if(!err) {
            res.json(rows);
        }
    });

    connection.on('error', function(err) {
          res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
          return;
    });
 });
```

What i want to do is that if now admin add new message in the message table it will come instantly on user side as currently i am using jquery and interval to check any messages .

Comment: What exactly is your issue?  I would suggest using web-sockets instead of polling your database.  Will give you more of a "realtime" feel to it.

Comment: Well the problem is that currently i am checking the data after some interval using jquery . What i want is that a trigger or something that send the data instantly as it is added in database . Its a one side communication that admin send some messages and time is very important . Currently i am getting some delay due to interval and i want to find a way to make it real time

Comment: I believe web-sockets will do what your looking for. http://socket.io/

Comment: and it also use nodejs